# Paypal (India to India) payment error in live mode

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I have implemented Paypal payment gateway. Sandbox testing was successful using card provided by PAYPAL. But in live mode users are getting error while completing payment. 
Wsers are getting error as "**We are not able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please return to the merchant's website and try using a different payment method (if available)**".

**Additional Information:**
my Bank account attached to PAYPAL is with "Canera bank" (India Bank)
all users are from India (users are using Master/Visa/ Amex cards)
{I have written to Paypal about my error but i am expecting reply in day or two}

Comment: I have received reply from PAYPAL as "Currently we can not perform **India to India** transactions however **India to International** transactions are possible. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indian users will not be able to make purchases from Indian merchants/sellers. This is sue to the fact that INR is not supported in INDIA as well as PayPal only has Crossborder transactions enabled for Indian sellers. This may change in the near future.However, as the current is You cannot do India to India transaction with PayPal.